# How can I conver a transcribed .wav into txt in full extent. - Google Speech API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

I'm having trouble with converting full transcribed speech to a text file. Eventually, I get what I need but not the entire text from the audio file. Let me note this (1 Pic),[image] I can see the whole text when I use print() function but get only one line of that text when I try to write it to .txt file (2 Pic).[image]

Also, you can look at my code if you need additional info and stuff. Thank you in advance!

```
from google.cloud import speech
import os



os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'PATH'

   

client = speech.SpeechClient()


with open('sample.wav', "rb") as audio_file:
    content = audio_file.read()

audio = speech.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
config = speech.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code="en-US",
    # Enable automatic punctuation
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True,
)

response = client.recognize(config=config, audio=audio)

for result in response.results:
    extr = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    print(extr)
    with open("guru9.txt","w+") as f:
        f.write(extr)
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your code is, per iteration you open, write, close your file. You should move out your opening and closing of your file outside the loop.

```
myfile = open("guru9.txt","w+")
for result in response.results:
    extr = result.alternatives[0].transcript
    myfile.write(extr)
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Right! It solved my problem and I really learned something useful! Thanx!